# Switching between Artifact and Project dependencies in gradle build.gradle.kts

Tags: kotlin, gradle, continuous-integration, dependency-management

I develop rather small multi module project. I find it useful to declare project dependencies so Idea automatically find sources and recompile them as needed. My dependency block in `build.gradle.kts` looks like:

```
implementation(project(":server"))
implementation(project(":project-models"))
implementation(project(":base-models"))
```

but for production build I need to change it to artifact dependency with fixed versions like:

```
implementation("cz.simplecoin.server:0.1.3")
implementation("cz.simplecoin:project-models:0.0.16")
implementation("cz.simplecoin:base-models:0.0.22")
```

I keep both blocks and commenting them in and out manually, which is not sexy and I keep forgetting about it.

I found https://discuss.gradle.org/t/switching-between-artifact-and-project-dependencies/7286 this article but it's 10 years old. Gradle come long way since then so there might be in house solution but i could not find any in official gradle docs, thought it's complex think.

I'm fine with providing versions manually. I know it can be done using some scripting like providing parameter in automated build and using it like:

```
if (properties["productionBuild"] == null) {
    implementation(project(":server"))        
} else {
    implementation("cz.simplecoin.server:0.1.3")
}
```

Which is almost what I want, except I need to specify packages and real projects paths in another file. This must be common problem of many, is there better way?